# Textstyle is not woking in release

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, material-components-android, textstyle

I am creating textview dynamically and setting the style like this

```
 val textView = TextView(context).apply {
            tag = data.id
            text = data.name
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            layoutParams = params
            TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.customStyle)
            setOnClickListener {  }
        }
```

This is the style

```
<style name="customStyle">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/quicksand_bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/icon_grey</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

It works fine when shrinkResources and minifyEnabled are false. It shows blank in the release (shrinkResources and minifyEnabled are true).

Comment: you need to add keep in proguard as your shrinker thinks that font quicksand_bold is not used anywhere in the code so it removes it from the build